# create requirement.txt file for virtualenv using Makefile not working

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to setup a makefile to create a virtual environment using Make in Windows.
I want to create an empty requirement.txt file from within the Makefile. This file shall be filled later with pip-package names.

The Code to create the empty file in windows looks like this:

```
build/requirements.txt:
echo >> //C:\Users\xxx\environments\venv\homepage\requirement.txt
```

When I run the Makefile no file is created. But when I use the command in Powershell directly, it creates the requirements.txt file.

I suppose it has something to do with Escaping the command. but I couldnt find any hint how to do this.
Has anyone an Idea, why the file is not created from the Makefile?

Merci A

Comment: As with your other question, please show the command you typed, the output you got, and explain what is not right about that output / what you wanted to happen (please cut and paste actual output, no paraphrasing, with proper formatting).  Also, you should remove the `@` prefix from all commands so that you can see exactly what make is invoking.

Comment: I recommend that you use forward-slashes, not backslashes, in the pathnames you put into makefile recipes.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the syntax must be like that:

```
build/requirements.txt:
   type nul >> environments/venv/homepage/requirements.txt
```

The reason is, that Make writes to the $USER folder as standard. So that is the starting point for any PATH used here.